# I don't understand why we can just extend the domain of this function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

**The problem**: Let $$g(x)= \left\{
\begin{matrix}
x & , \, 0 \leq x \leq 1/2\\
1-x& , \, 1/2 \leq x \leq 1
\end{matrix} \right .$$
Prove that $$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{g(2^kx)}{2^k}$$ converges uniformly to a continous function $f$.

---

**My solution**: Notice that $g(x)$ exist only when $x\in [0,1]$. Since $2^n \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$, if $x>0$ then $2^nx >1$ for sufficiently large $n$, therefore for $x=0, \ \{S_n(x)\}$ converges to $f(x)=0$, and for any other value of $x, \ S_n(x)$  doesn't exist when $n\to \infty$, so $f$ is undefined. Since the uniform converges definition is true for all $x\in\{0\}$ and since $x=0$ is not an accumulation point of $f, \ \{S_n(x)\}$ converges uniformly to $f$, which is continous.

---

**Teacher's solution**: Extend the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)=g(x+1)$, then $g(x)\leq 1/2, \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, so $$\frac{g(2^nx)}{2^n} < \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$ By Weiertrass' M Criterion, $\{S_n(x)\}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and since every $g(2^nx)/2^n$ is continous, so is $f$

---

Now, I don't understand why extending the domain of $g$ is valid here, isn't it like adding an extra condition that the problem doens't give?

Comment: It's not adding a condition; really you are replacing $g$ by another function $\tilde g$ which restricts to $g$ on $[0,1]$. Rather than using a new letter, people will abuse notation slightly and just write $g$ for $\tilde g$.

Comment: I do not agree with Elliot G! As you point out, $g(x)$ is not defined when $x\notin[0,1]$, which prevent defining $S_n(x)$ for $x∉ 0$. This seems obviously an error in the question. Your answer is correct from my point of view (but you could also have corrected the question and guess the most obvious extension!).

Sometimes being right does not imply being relevant ...

Comment: By the way, as $n$ approaches $\infty$, this becomes the [Blancmange curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve)

Comment: @LL you're right. I didn't notice $S_n(x)$ uses $g(2^kx)$ before commenting. This looks to be an error in the statement.

Comment: @LL3.14 so I could just extend $g$ such that $g(x)=0$ for $x$ outside $[0, 1]$? That's... awfully anticlimatic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$g$ is only defined over $[0,1]$, yet $x$ may be any real number. Extending $g$ gives definition to the cases when its argument falls outside $[0,1]$, such as $k=2$ and $x=\frac13$. Extending $g$ per the teacher's answer (periodically) makes the function behave in a more regular (read: easier to understand) way, while guaranteeing that the bounds on $\frac{g(2^kx)}{2^k}$ fall fast enough to apply the Weierstrass M-test.

$f$ is in fact the [blancmange or Takagi curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve). The part in $[0,1]$ is shown below:
[image]